# How can I conditionally fill color using two variables in ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2, colors, overlay, fill, categorical-data

I am fairly new to R, and I am trying to create a scatterplot in which the fill of points (representing study sites) depends on the variable, acceleration. However, I also want to omit the fill in points that are located in a delta (or, SitesDataCompiled$deltaic=1). What would I need to add to my code to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

```
figuredata <- SitesDataCompiled[order(SitesDataCompiled$SelectedSite),]
ggplot(data = figuredata,aes(x = figuredata$Acceleration, y = figuredata$ElChange, fill = figuredata$LandChange, shape= as.factor(SelectedSite), size=3)) + 
  geom_point(color= "black", shape = 21, stroke = 1)+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("0" = 21, "1" = 24))
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3), limits=c(-3,3))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-25,0,25,50,75), limits=c(-25,75))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors= rainbow(5))+
  guides(size="none", shape= "none")
```

I tried creating an if else function, but I'm not sure how to use that with scale_fill_continuous or if that is the right approach.

Comment: Are you trying to just remove the points in the delta from your plot? Or are you trying to make them a certain color that's not in `rainbow`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking for exactly, but here are two solutions.
Note that you don't need to use `$` once you have already named your data in the `data` argument.

1. If you simply want to remove all data where `deltaic == 1`, use a filter and then plot.

```
figuredata <- SitesDataCompiled[order(SitesDataCompiled$SelectedSite),]

figuredata %>% 
  filter(deltaic != 1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Acceleration, y = ElChange, fill = LandChange, shape= as.factor(SelectedSite), size=3)) + 
  geom_point(color= "black", shape = 21, stroke = 1)+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("0" = 21, "1" = 24))
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3), limits=c(-3,3))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-25,0,25,50,75), limits=c(-25,75))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors= rainbow(5)) +
  guides(size="none", shape= "none")
```

2. If you would like your data to be a different color than the rainbow where there is a delta, there are a few ways to accomplish this. The simplest (although a bit hack-ish) is to utilize the built-in `na.value` parameter in `scale_fill_gradientn`. This parameter allows you to set a separate color for all data points that are labeled `NA`. We accomplish this by changing the `LandChange` variable to `NA` where `deltaic == 1`. Then, you are free to change the value of `na.value` in `scale_fill_gradientn` to whatever color you want.

```
figuredata %>% 
  mutate(LandChange = case_when(deltaic == 1 ~ NA, TRUE ~ LandChange)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Acceleration, y = ElChange, fill = LandChange, shape= as.factor(SelectedSite), size=3)) + 
  geom_point(color= "black", shape = 21, stroke = 1)+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("0" = 21, "1" = 24))
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3), limits=c(-3,3))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-25,0,25,50,75), limits=c(-25,75))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors= rainbow(5), na.value = "black") +
  guides(size="none", shape= "none")
```